# Select dropdown box z-index issue on modal window

Tags: html, css, format, z-index

I have the below dropdown that I have linked to a image map modal window with an link.  However the selection list is on top of the modal window even though the modal is set to `z-index: 99999;`

Any thoughts on how to get the selection box to not overlay the modal window?  Can I set the z-index of the selection list somehow?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Seeing the issue in Firefox and Chrome so far

Comment: Z-index property can be used for fixed or absolute positioned elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp):

> The z-index property specifies the stack order of an element.
>
> An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element
>   with a lower stack order.
>
> Note: z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute,
>   position:relative, or position:fixed).

Most likely therefore, you need to set `position:relative` on the modal window (unless you want the attributes of fixed or absolute positioning, obviously).